# Rails 6 find last element in has_many relation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to create a query which returns all unsold `products` based on their last element of relation with `shipment`. Simpler to say I want to avoid N+1 query issue and replace code below by one line join probably.

```
products = Product.unsold.select do |product|
  product.shipments.last.created_at < 5.days.ago
end
```

And then update `sold` column for these products

```
products.each { |product| product.update(sold: true) }
```

Models:

```
class Product
  has_many :shipments

  scope :unsold, -> { where(sold: false) }
end

class Shipment
  belongs_to :product
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this join query

```
Shipment.joins(:product).where(shipments: { created_at < 5.days.ago })
```

Comment: Naah, that won't work either - `ERROR:  column reference "created_at" is ambiguous)`. I've just realized that to avoid N+1 query the only thing I need to do is to `includes(:shippments)` to be `Product.includes(:shippments).where(sold: false).select do |product| ... `

Comment: try this `Shipment.joins(:product).where("shipments.created_at < ?", 5.days.ago)`

Answer (score 0):

If the sole aim is to avoid N+1 query, then you can try this

```
unsold_products = Product.unsold.includes(:shipment)
unsold_products.each...
```

This is called eager loading, a single query is run and both products and shipments are retrieved. Then you can iterate from there.